# Is this problem statement for proving the determinant of a block-matrix possibly incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A, B,C,D$ be square matrices, of same size $n\times n$.

Assume $A$ is invertible and $AC = CA.$

Prove that

$$
    det    \begin{bmatrix}
        A & B \\
        C & D  \\
                \end{bmatrix}
 =   det[AD - BC]
        $$

I am getting my final answer as $det[AD - CB]$ instead, and my work looks fine -- just a simple factorization of the matrix, and using the multiplicativity of the determinant, $AA^{-1}=I$, and $AC=CA$.

Is the problem statement wrong?  Or perhaps my answer of $det[AD - CB]$ is actually equal to $det[AD - BC]$, but I doubt it -- there are no extra assumptions on the relations of $B$ and $C$ other than that they are of the same size.  So we can't assume that $B$ and $C$ commute.

Thanks,

Comment: The best way to sort this out is to test the formulas on some actual examples. (A computer algebra system is perfect for that).

Comment: isn't it $\det(AD - CB)$?

Comment: To build non trivial commuting matrices $A$ and $C$, try taking diagonal matrices $D_A, D_C$ and conjugating it with the same invertible matrix $P$, that is: $A=PD_AP^{-1}, C=PD_CP^{-1}$.

Comment: Hi @user251257 - yes, my answer agrees with yours.  I am betting at this point that the problem statement is wrong.  But I am also considering what Guiseppe Negro is suggesting, too.  Thanks...

Comment: Hi @GiuseppeNegro, why would we want to build commuting matrices A and C, when the issue is with the matrices B and C?  Thanks,

Comment: @LebronJames:  Your hypothesis is that $A,C$ commute, right?

Comment: Hi @hardmath -- yes, absolutely.  Hmm...can I deduce something about the relation between B and C from this...

Comment: Hi @hardmath, does the assumption that A and C commute tell us something about the relation between B and C?  I don't see any, unfortunately...

Comment: While no special relationship between $B$ and $C$ can be deduced, it is true that $\det BC = \det CB$.

Comment: Hi @hardmath, yes - I had thought of that, but the final answer is in the form of det( difference of matrices ), not det(product of matrices).  So I still don't see the justification for swapping the order of CB.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: You are right and your book is wrong.

Comment: I mean, take some $2\times 2$ matrices and test both formulas, to see if one of them does not hold.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much, @user1551 - have a great day :-)